# Do we do anything about deliberaty copy+pasted threads from SE appearing on other sites?

Tags: discussion

I was google searching myself earlier, and came across this "blog" which directly copy+pasted an entire question thread from EE.SE I wasn't 100% sure, but didn't *think* we either do, or at least *should* allow this.

"Blog" post:
[I need help with a simple IR circuit...](http://www.stars-blog.com/i-need-help-with-a-simple-ir-circuit-to-control-electromagnets/)
Our Thread:
[I need help with a simple IR circuit...](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/215254/i-need-help-with-a-simple-ir-circuit-to-control-electromagnets)

Answer (score 2):

The site you linked to has scraped large numbers of posts from Stack Exchange without attribution. The following link from meta.SE is a good overview of the issues:

[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

I have taken the step of notifying StackExchange for this site.